# Strange dialog with laptop internal keyboard

Tags: windows-8, laptop, keyboard

I have a Lenovo 31900056 Pro laptop with Windows 8 installed on it.

There is a strange effect with how the keyboard works. I don't know how this happened. The Keyboard layout and language setup are fine. When I connect a USB keyboard it works as it should, but the laptop's one does not.

For example when I try to input "panel sterowania" (**control panel** in Polish), this text shows up in the input dialog: "pazhjmnel.\ sxgberowazhjmniaz". What is this all about and how to correct the problem ?

Comment: I realized that probably same liquid had contact with keyboard. arrow keys also doesn't work in bios menu. Can someone write how to open keyboard to clean it up ?

Comment: Search for the service manual for your laptop

Comment: I've found generally fixing damaged laptop keyboards to be a lost cause. Easier to just look up the part number and get a new one